# How to parse second identical tag of first 5 listings and the first identical tag of the last 5 listings of a website

Tags: html, parsing, web-scraping

I was web scraping: https://www.carehome.co.uk/care_search_results.cfm/searchunitary/Tower-Hamlets and isolated the relevant html to scrape the title

I want to output the text from the second  for the first 5 listings of care home website. The first listing should return "Silk Court" as an example.

I want the output for the second 5 listings as well, these have 1  tag per listing. I.e. Coxley lodge.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

```
 #SCRIPT
    from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
    from selenium import webdriver


    #grabspage and parses it through ready for picking apart
    my_url = "https://www.carehome.co.uk/care_search_results.cfm/searchunitary/Tower-Hamlets"

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:/Users/lemonade/Documents/work/chromedriver')
    driver.get(my_url)
    page_s = soup(driver.page_source, features='html.parser')

    #Finds relvant divs
    containers = page_s.findAll("div", {"class": "home-name"})


    for container in containers:
        name_container = container.p
        all_a = name_container.findAll("a")
        print(all_a)


OUTPUT
[<a name="member_21310"></a>, <a href="https://www.carehome.co.uk/carehome.cfm/searchazref/20001005SILA" style="font-weight:bold;font-size:28px">Silk Court</a>]
[<a name="member_35665"></a>, <a href="https://www.carehome.co.uk/carehome.cfm/searchazref/10001005FITA" style="">Westport Care Home</a>]
[<a name="member_34393"></a>, <a href="https://www.carehome.co.uk/carehome.cfm/searchazref/20001005ASPA" style="font-weight:bold;font-size:28px">Aspen Court Care Home</a>]
[<a name="member_4936"></a>, <a href="https://www.carehome.co.uk/carehome.cfm/searchazref/10001005SYDA" style="">Beaumont Court</a>]
[<a name="member_40189"></a>, <a href="https://www.carehome.co.uk/carehome.cfm/searchazref/20001005HAWA" style="font-weight:bold;font-size:28px">Hawthorn Green Residential and Nursing Home</a>]
[<a href="https://www.carehome.co.uk/carehome.cfm/searchazref/10001005COXA">
                                Coxley House
                            </a>]
[<a href="https://www.carehome.co.uk/carehome.cfm/searchazref/85852">
                                Toby Lodge
                            </a>]
[<a href="https://www.carehome.co.uk/carehome.cfm/searchazref/10001005HOTA">
                                Hotel in the Park
                            </a>]
[<a href="https://www.carehome.co.uk/carehome.cfm/searchazref/10001005RETB">
                                34/35 Huddleston Close
                            </a>]
[<a href="https://www.carehome.co.uk/carehome.cfm/searchazref/10001005APPA">
                                Approach Lodge
                            </a>]
```

Comment: What does "second five" listings mean ? Does that mean 6-10 ?

Comment: yes 1-5 is the first 5 listings and 6-10 is the second 5.  Thank you!

Comment: With css you would do: `:nth-child(n+6):nth-child(-n+10)`